# Source code control for Oracle Forms/Reports Builder

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Am looking and testing all the source control solutions to use with Oracle Forms/Reports builders. but, none of the existing solutions works well with Oracle products. Any one out there did a similar practice? and how do you control the source codes of Oracle Forms/Reports?

Answer (score 3):

What we used to do (I no longer work with Forms or Reports) is convert the forms and reports to text files (.fmt files for Forms, I forget the file extension for Reports) and put those text files into the version control system (which was PVCS).

Comment: +1 Additionally, in the more recent versions of Oracle Forms and Reports, at least from version 9 onwards, it is also possible to convert to an XML-file. Which you can also put into version control, instead of the .fmt and .rdt

Answer (score 0):

In Forms 11g developer one option is available to create .txt file of the form source. We are doing baseline in SVN  this .txt file.
File->Admin->object list report